# Run workflow when item added to specific column

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

Ok Say you have 3 columns in a list `date1`, `date2` and `date3`. Each column has its own worklow: `work1`, `work2` and `work3`.

Is it possible using sharepoint designer  to only run a workflow when a item is added to a specific column?

For example when item is added to the column `date1` only run workflow `work1` and when item added to column `date2` only run `work2` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Short of writing an event receiver as SigarDave has suggested, it is not possible to only run the workflow when a particular field has changed. Further, it is not possible in a workflow to detect which field initiated the change. However, there are workarounds.

This question should be very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014351/how-can-i-tell-what-change-initiated-a-workflow

I would go with the second suggestion by Paige Watson in that question - create a 2nd column that holds the "old" value, when the workflow runs, check to see if the "old value" and "new value" are different, if they are not, exit the workflow. Don't forget to update the "old value" when it is different, and also when the item is created.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to accomplish this is by using the event receiver for the List Item

In that You can check for the Item added and Item Updated events.

For Item Added You can check the Value of Date1 Date2 and Date which one has a value , according to that you can trigger the workflow

In ITEM Updated event you can for the List Item's After Properties and before properties .

Compare them and Make sure which column is updated, and according to that Kickoff the workflow.

Please refer this
http://zimmergren.net/technical/starting-a-sharepoint-workflow-from-code-event-receiver

Let me know if it helps you or You find any other solution.

Thanks